# Why is my program crashing right after my `Print()` function is executed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've stepped through it and still can find no discernable reason why it is crashing. Everything is working until I get through to the end of the `Print()` function. Entire program looks like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringSet
{

    class StringSet
    {

        private List<List<string>> _Buckets;
        private int _numStrings;

        public StringSet ( ) 
        {
            this._Buckets = new List<List<string>>();
            this._numStrings = 0;
        }

        public StringSet ( string[] S )
        {
            // better way to do this?
            this._Buckets = new List<List<string>>();
            foreach ( string s in S ) this._Buckets.Add(new List<string>());
            foreach ( string s in S ) { this.Insert(s);  }
        }

        private int _GetBucketNumber ( string s, List<List<string>> Buckets )
        {
            //       s: string whose index to look up
            // Buckets: source buckets

            // disallow empty or NULL strings
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ) { throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add empty or NULL string to set"); }
            if ( Buckets.Count == 0 ) { throw new ArgumentException("Tried to call _GetBucketNumber on empty bucket list"); }

            // XOR characters together and mod by length of buckets
            char c = s[0];
            for ( int i = 1; i < s.Length; ++i ) { c ^= s[i]; }
            return (int)c % Buckets.Count;
        }

        private void _RehashIfNecessary ( )
        {
            // if the number of strings in the set exceeds the number of buckets, 
            // increase the number of buckets to either double its current size 
            // or the largest number of buckets possible, whichever is smaller
            if ( this._numStrings > this._Buckets.Count )
            {
                List<List<string>> NewBuckets = new List<List<string>>(Math.Min(this._Buckets.Count * 2, Int32.MaxValue));
                foreach ( List<string> Bucket in this._Buckets )
                {
                    foreach ( string s in Bucket )
                    {
                        NewBuckets[this._GetBucketNumber(s, NewBuckets)].Add(s);
                    }
                }
                this._Buckets = NewBuckets;
            }
        }

        public void Insert ( string s )
        {
            // disallow empty or NULL strings
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ) { throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add empty or NULL string to set"); }

            // Get bucket that string belongs in
            List<string> Bucket = this._Buckets[this._GetBucketNumber(s,this._Buckets)];
            // Add if not already there
            if ( Bucket.IndexOf(s) == -1 ) { Bucket.Add(s); }
            ++_numStrings; _RehashIfNecessary();
        }

        public bool Contains ( string s )
        {
            // returns true or false depending on whether s is a 
            // string currently in the set

            return (this._Buckets[this._GetBucketNumber(s,this._Buckets)].IndexOf(s) != -1);
        }

        public void Print ( )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < this._Buckets.Count; ++i )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bucket {0}: {1}", i, string.Join(",",this._Buckets[i].ToArray()));
            }
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main ( string[] args )
        {
            string[] strs = new string[] { "apple", "potato", "car", "cat", "dog", "sheep", "Trump" };
            try
            {
                StringSet TestSet = new StringSet(strs);
                TestSet.Print();
            }
            catch ( Exception E )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured: {0}", E.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, the creating of the hash set works just fine (Ideally there would be 1 element in each bucket)

[image]

but then it crashes with the errors

```
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\StringSet\StringSet\bin\Debug\StringSet.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x12ec has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1524 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'StringSet.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: StringSet.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\StringSet\StringSet\bin\Debug\StringSet.exe'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x180c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1aa4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[2556] StringSet.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Have tried for the longest time and can't figure out what is going wrong!

Comment: Agreed it looks like everything ran fine. It printed out all of your strings and exited with code 0.

Comment: Try rreading the output. Last line: "The program '[2556] StringSet.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).". Exit Code 0 for the last 100 years or so (ok, not THAT much) meant no error. Ergo: Program existed. Console programs do that at the end of code.

Answer (score 2):

It is not crashing, the console window gets terminated after completion of code please put a Console.Read() call after catch block